# Render first element of set using quarkus qute template engine

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

While trying to render first element of set using quarkus qute  template engine it is throwing the below xception.

> io.quarkus.qute.TemplateException: Rendering error in template
> [index.html] line 93: Property "0" not found on the base object
> "java.util.LinkedHashSet" in expression {appDetails.imageUrls.0}

Code used to render

```
<img src="{appDetails.imageUrls[0]}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since as mentioned in the error imageUrls is of type **Set**. So use **iterator().next()** method to get the first element.

```
 <img src="{appDetails.imageUrls.iterator().next()}" />
```